# Post Request responded 500 on HTTPClient in Asp .net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, webapi, postasync

Request response:

```
{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Date: Mon, 03 Oct 2022 06:47:30 GMT
}}
```

Here I am requesting an .netCore Web API for saving user information. Where I have Hosted an API in local IIS and its working when I am calling a `GetUserList` method, but when I am calling `SaveUser` method with `POSTAsync` its provide below error. Please help me about this issue.
My request Method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveUser(string name, string email, string mobile, string address, string passwrod,
            string userrole)
        {
            User usernew = new User();

            usernew.Name = name;
            usernew.Email = email;
            usernew.Mobile = mobile;
            usernew.Address = address;
            usernew.Password = passwrod;
           usernew.UsrRoleId = 1;

            var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(usernew);
          
            HttpContent postContent = new StringContent(json2, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(burl + "User/SaveUser", postContent);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
               
            }
            else
            {
               
            }
            return Redirect("Index");
        }
```

Here I have added API Controller method

API Method contains this code:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("SaveUser")]
        [Consumes("application/json")]
        public IActionResult SaveUser(User user)
        {
            User us = new User();
            us.Name = user.Name;
            us.Email =user.Email;
            us.Mobile = user.Mobile;
            us.Address = user.Address;
            us.Password = PasswordEnc(user.Password);

            _UserRepository.SaveUser(us);            
             return Ok(true);                      
        }
```

Comment: Did you try `await client.PostAsJsonAsync(burl + "User/SaveUser", postContent);`?

Comment: Can you share your request as well? Also, add a try-catch clause around endpoints and log the error.

Comment: @Ibrahim Yes, I Have Also Tried with  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(burl + "User/SaveUser", postContent);

Comment: @klekmek I have added API methods on my question

Comment: What does your logging tell you?

Comment: @MdSafiulAlam Do you have an exception in your API `SaveUser` method by try-catch? Does this method get hit?

Comment: @Ibrahim API Method (SaveUser) get hit with Null Value, that's why not saved in database

Comment: @MdSafiulAlam Yes I suspected the issue was at saving the user. Did you manage to fix the null issue? If you still have issue there, you can post the exception log.

Comment: @Ibrahim I think there has a problem with HTTPContent, Because data serialized and json2 variable is ok but when convert to HTTPConent with StringContent ,Encoding.UTF8 make its null and POST to API as a null value.

Comment: @Ibrahim  I have already used [FROMBODY]/[FROMHEADER]/[FROMFROM] but output is same

Comment: @MdSafiulAlam Can you post your request like this `var result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(burl + "User/SaveUser", usernew);` and then on the API method, temporarily remove `[Consumes("application/json")]`. Do this and let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248518/discussion-between-ibrahim-and-md-safiul-alam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use `client.PostAsJsonAsync` as it automatically does the conversion for you to `json`. You would implement your post request as below:

```
User usernew = new User();

usernew.Name = name;
usernew.Email = email;
usernew.Mobile = mobile;
usernew.Address = address;
usernew.Password = passwrod;
usernew.UsrRoleId = 1;

var result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(burl + "User/SaveUser", usernew);
```